# How to stream video from c++ to a web

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming

I want to stream a video from a c++ client to a nodejs server which would create a video file that a web client could play.
The video I received is processed image by image with ffmpeg and each image is stored in this struct:

```
struct CameraRGBImage {
    std::vector<uint8_t> rawData;
    int height;
    int width; 
};
```

Right now what the program does is use OpenCV to create an image from that struct (a Mat object) and show it with imshow creating a video on the local machine.

What I want to do is to send that same video to my nodejs server and create an .mp4 file there which would be accesed from the web client.

This is my c++ client now (It is simplified using a .mp4 video instead of the struct since the important thing I think is the Mat):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "config.h"

#define SERVER_IP "192.168.50.6"
#define SERVER_PORT 8888
#define PACKET_SIZE 65500

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc ,const char* args[]){
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        cerr << "Error creating socket" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    int jpegqual =  ENCODE_QUALITY;

    Mat frame, send;
    vector < uchar > encoded;

    VideoCapture cap("test.mp4"); // open the video
    namedWindow("send", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) { // check if we succeeded
        cerr << "Failed to open camera";
        return 1;
    }

    clock_t last_cycle = clock();
    while (1) {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.size().width==0)continue;//simple integrity check; skip erroneous data...
        resize(frame, send, Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);
        vector < int > compression_params;
        compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
        compression_params.push_back(jpegqual);
        imencode(".jpg", send, encoded, compression_params);
        imshow("send", send);

        int total_pack = 1 + (encoded.size() - 1) / PACK_SIZE;

        sendto(sock, &total_pack, sizeof(total_pack), 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

        for (int i = 0; i < total_pack; i++)
            sendto(sock, & encoded[i * PACK_SIZE], PACK_SIZE, 0,  (const struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

        waitKey(FRAME_INTERVAL);

        clock_t next_cycle = clock();
        double duration = (next_cycle - last_cycle) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "\teffective FPS:" << (1 / duration) << " \tkbps:" << (PACK_SIZE * total_pack / duration / 1024 * 8) << endl;

        cout << next_cycle - last_cycle;
        last_cycle = next_cycle;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I do not know how to recreate the video on the server, this is what I have now:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const jpeg = require('jpeg-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const PORT = 8888;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

let data = []; // array to store received packet data
let expectedPackets = 0; // expected total number of packets
let receivedPackets = 0; // current number of received packets
let imageData = null; // variable to store the image data

server.on('message', (msg, remoteInfo) => {
    if (receivedPackets === 0) {
        expectedPackets = msg.readInt32LE()+1; // calculate the expected total number of packets
        receivedPackets++;
        return;
    }

    data.push(msg); // add the received packet to the data array
    receivedPackets++;

    if (receivedPackets === expectedPackets) {
        receivedPackets = 0;
        // if all packets have been received, concatenate the data and display as an image
        imageData = Buffer.concat(data);
        data = []

        const decodedImage = jpeg.decode(imageData, true);

        // output the decoded image to a file
        fs.writeFileSync('out.jpg', Buffer.from(decodedImage.data));

        // add the image to the video
        ffmpeg('video.mp4')
        .input('out.jpg')
        .output('test2.mp4')
        .run();
    }
});

server.on('listening', function () {
    const address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

When I start receiving I get this error which I think indicates that the received image is corrupt:

```
/mnt/Almacen/VBox/Prueba udp/node_modules/jpeg-js/lib/decoder.js:114
          throw new Error("unexpected marker: " + ((bitsData << 8) | nextByte).toString(16));
```

What I wanted to know is if there is an easier way to do this and if there is none, how could I fix this?